# Can't disable trailing slash redirect in .NET Web Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, friendly-url

I my RouteConfig class I have category URLs with a trailing slash at the end:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
      "ListAll",
      "list/",
      "~/browseall.aspx", true
  );
```

When I run my site, the url `10.0.0.1/list/` redirects (301 redirect) to the same URL without the trailing slash. This is the only mapped route in `RouteConfig.cs` file.

What I've checked/did:

- I commented out the `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)`
- There are no rewrite rules in the `web.config`
- There is no redirect in the code behind of the page
- Checked the `global.asax`, but there is not route config code there
- Check IIS rewrite rules, but no rules there
- Added `routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true`

What is causing this redirection?

Using ASP.NET and running code on local IIS 7.5 in Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the browser cache solved it. I don't understand what it has to do with it, but it worked.